# Java: How to stop console input from typing a certain character

Tags: java, console, boolean

I'm making a hangman program, and I want to have a ton of Booleans for the alphabet / letters / symbols, and what they would do is, when they are true, I want the console to DISALLOW the typing of that character.

For example: I have typed g as a character and pressed Enter. My program now has the g=true boolean. I need system.forceConsole.input.stop(forLetter:g) or some jazz like that so it CANNOT even be an option to type g in console again.

I only want to know if this is even remotely possible, and if it is... could I see a cut/paste example to see if it what I'm looking for?

Below is just a little example code of what I'm thinking of, by no means will this actually work, but it should show what I'm going for...

```
      input = new Scanner(System.in);
      boolean a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z;
      //set all listed booleans to false
      char userCharacter;


      System.out.print("Please enter a letter");
      userCharacter=input.nextChar();
      if (userCharacter==letterArray){//That would be an array to get the letters 
                                      //Still don't know how to use them
      if (letterArray == true)
      {System.deny.Console.input(forChar:letterArray)}
      }
```

The biggest thing I'm looking at trying to see if it even exists in some other System code is the "System.deny.Console.input" thing, I'm not worried about the program not working because, this is just "example" code that was not meant to work - but to get a point across. So you don't have to critique me on the way the code looks, because it is rather difficult to make the "code" blotches on the site so I didn't really want to make it really elaborate.

Comment: When you say you're storing 'a ton of booleans', I presume that's in an array (`boolean letters[] = new boolean[26]`)?

Comment: Well, currently I know nothing about arrays so, no, I was just gonna have a rather long list of them like boolean a, b, c, d, e ... a=false; b=false;c=false etc

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like the following:

```
public class Hangman {
  boolean usedLetters[] = new boolean[26];
  boolean gameOver = true;

  String inputString = "";
  char testLetter = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Initialize each boolean in the array to 'false'.
    Arrays.fill(usedLetters, false);

    System.out.println("Try a letter by typing it and pressing enter");
    System.out.println("(additional letters will be ignored, lower case only)");


    while (!gameOver) {
      // Get the characters entered on the console before enter is pressed
      inputString = System.console.readLine();

      // Get the first letter entered and adjust the value so that a = 0, b = 1, etc...
      testLetter = inputString.toCharArray()[0] - 'a';

      // Check to see if the letter is valid
      if (testLetter <= 25 && testLetter >= 0) {
        // Check if letter has beed tried before
        if (!usedLetters[testLetter]) {
          // Do something to check the letter
          tryLetter(testLetter);
          // Remember that the letter has been tried
          usedLetters[testLetter] = true;
        } else {
          // Do nothing
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static tryLetter(char letter) {
    // Insert your code to update the display here.
    // Remember to set 'gameOver' to 'true' when you want to stop accepting input.
  }
}
```

Although this is a complete class, it won't really do anything useful on its own, since there is no actual game logic in there.

Comment: It's full of red :o http://prntscr.com/5xvtm4 I'm not really familiar with anything you put in there (most of the arrays are like a different language) I don't know if I have to have any includes at the top, I always put include java.util.* cause I use it for scanners, so I dunno what all I need to put to make it not red :l Also, from the looks of what I "do" know about the coding, it seems like it's just going to type the character, but when you press enter it might not show up? I dunno too complex for me to understand as it stands xD