# Filter character of console input in Java

Tags: java, console

I'm writing a terminal version of my Java application, and this is the first time I do this. I tried `Scanner` and `Console`, but as far as I investigated, these classes only allow me to receive user input after he/she finish inputting (no manipulating/filtering).

For example, I want the user inputs his age, but if he inputs a meaningless string, all I can do is validating the string and requesting him to input again. What I really want is only allow him to input integer, i.e when he press any key which is not a number, the character will not be displayed on console. Using Swing and `JTextField` I can do this easily with `DocumentFilter`, but with console only, I still haven't found a way.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks all.

Comment: I dont think it is possible

Comment: console input, at least in the usual manner, usually requires an `<enter>` so i can see that this might be difficult...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164773/java-how-to-stop-console-input-from-typing-a-certain-character

Comment: Controlling console input at that granularity is not possible in pure Java. There are platform-specific, non-standard ways to achieve this, but they should only be pursued if you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Please can you show me the way! My app is platform-specific already (KDE Linux with Konsole).

Answer (score 0):

Java has something called robot API which u can use to control keyboard mouse etc...
Not the recommended way :)

Since the console is not Java program (its a c program) you have limited way to interface with it, perhaps you can write native API to get more control over it. I have not tried it but if needed use this option.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I have messed around with terminal input using C++ before, but I really don't want to use JNI here unless it is the last option.

Comment: The robot is for *emulating* user input, not for *filtering* it.